AzureAD OIDC: access_token from https://sts.windows.net/ is not a JWT token
I'm implementing the authorization_code flow with AzureAD OIDC for my application in python using MSAL library.
I need to use v1 OAuth2 endpoints in order to require MFA authentication (which doesn't seem to be availabile in v2.0), so:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/

Instead of
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/

Here's the sample code:
msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id="xxx",
    client_credential="yyy",
    oidc_authority="https://sts.windows.net/{tenant}",  # Force OAuth2 v1.0
)

...

flow = msal_app.initiate_auth_code_flow(
    scopes=["User.Read"],
    redirect_uri="zzz",
)

# Redirect to: flow["auth_uri"] + "&amr_values=ngcmfa"  # OAuth2 v2.0 does not accept amr_values which requires the MFA authentication

...

payload = msal_app.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(flow, dict(request.query_params))

Here's what the payload contains:

It worked, but the access_token is weird, it does not appear to be a JWT token (which usually begins with ey).
If I try to use it with Microsoft Graph to use the User.Read scope I asked for, it fails:
requests.get(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {payload['access_token']}"}
    ).json()

{'error': {'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken', 'message': "IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.", 'innerError': {'date': '2024-06-03T08:58:59', 'request-id': 'qqq', 'client-request-id': 'www'}}}

So question: why is it giving an access_token that cannot be used?
Note: If I switch to OAuth2 v2.0, it works without issues and returns a valid JWT token in access_token, however, I cannot use amr_values to enforce MFA, which is a requirement.
Can you help me understanding what is going on?


Note that: To force Multiple factor authentication, you need to pass amr_values in the authorize URL. Refer this
MsDoc


And it supports only v1.0 endpoint.
In you code try to change authority as https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID. Refer this MsDoc

For sample, I modified the code by passing the authorize URL directly and got the results successfully:
# Create a Flask web application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'os.urandom(24)'  
 
client_id = "ClientID"
tenant_id = "TenantID"
redirect_uri = "RedirectURL"
 
msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id
)
# Define the authorization endpoint URL
auth_url = (
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
    + tenant_id
    + "/oauth2/authorize?"
    + "response_type=code&"
    + "client_id=" + client_id + "&"
    + "state=12345&"
    + "resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&"
    + "client-request-id=67890&"
    + "amr_values=ngcmfa&" 
    + "redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return redirect(auth_url)
@app.route("/get_a_token")
def get_a_token():
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    # Acquire an access token using the authorization code
    try:
        token_response = msal_app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            auth_code,
            scopes=["User.Read"],
            redirect_uri=redirect_uri
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Token acquisition failed: {str(e)}"
    if "access_token" in token_response:
        access_token = token_response["access_token"]
        print("Access Token:", access_token)
        # Use the access token to make a request to Microsoft Graph
        graph_response = requests.get(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
        )
        if graph_response.status_code == 200:
            user_data = graph_response.json()
            return f"User: {user_data['displayName']}, Email: {user_data['mail']}"
        else:
            return f"Failed to fetch user data from Microsoft Graph: {graph_response.text}"
    else:
        error_message = token_response.get("error_description", "Unknown error")
        return f"Token acquisition failed: {error_message}"
# Run the Flask application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

The user is redirected to MFA page:

And after successful sign-in I got the access token:

Using the access token, I am able to successfully query Micrsoft Graph API like below:

Reference:
Azure Active Directory multi-factor check for authorization - Stack Overflow by Joey Cai
